# Automatically cancel GitHub action if queue is taking too long

Tags: github-actions

In peak hours my routinely scheduled GitHub actions pile up in the queue waiting for a runner to carry out the job. Often I end up manually canceling the stuck actions. Is there a way to avoid this, and, for instance, to automatically have the action canceled if the waiting period for a runner to come online is too long?

Comment: not exactly what you are searching, but there is a concurrency property: 
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-concurrency